# How to generate a list of values related to angles of a polygon?

Tags: graphics

[image]

I want to generate this exact list

I have this code and it works perfectly however I want to do it in a different way without using these functions, can someone please help me do this?

```
x = 180 (p - 2 q)/p


DeleteCases[
 Flatten[
  Table[
   If[
    IntegerQ[x],
    If[x > 0,
     If[GCD[p, q] == 1,
      {p, q, x}
      ]
     ]
    ],
   {p, 3, 40, 1},
   {q, 1, p/2}],
  1
  ],
 Null
 ]
```

What is another solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you seen the examples regarding star polygons in the Applications section of the [documentation for `Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)?

Comment: Can you explain why did you rewrite the question which was already answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following, with your definition of `x`:

```
Select[
  Table[{p, q, x}, {p, 3, 40}, {q, 1, p/2}] ~ Flatten ~ 1,
  Apply[IntegerQ[#3] && #3 > 0 && GCD[#1, #2] == 1 &]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the `Table` code from your second code block and strip out the `Graphics` directives since I think that `ArrayPlot` is actually the most efficient way to plot this.

```
mytable = Table[
   Table[
    If[EvenQ[Binomial[col, k]], 1, 0], {col, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, col, 
     1}], {n, {7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255}}];
```

This is going to result in $mytable$ having 6 different ragged matrices (that is the first row will only have a single number, the second row 2 numbers, etc.). We can easily plot them with:

```
ArrayPlot /@ PadLeft /@ mytable
```

The `/@` notation basically means "iterate over all of the parts of whatever comes after" and is sometimes a nice substitute for `Table`. So `PadLeft/@mytable` is going to create rectangular matrices by padding the left side of each row with zeros, then we iterate over all of those padded matrices with ArrayPlot. This gets us:

[image: Sierpinski meshes]

Which doesn't have the exact same colouring as yours, but it acts as a quick check to make sure they look the same. If you decided you wanted to use `ArrayPlot` yourself, there are options for colouring it however you like.

```
tally = Tally /@ Flatten /@ mytable
fractions = N @ #[[2, 2]]/Total[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ tally
```

Now I use the `Tally` function on the original unpadded list. I have to `Flatten` it first since I want to see how many 0s and 1s there are, I don't want it to tell me how many of each list of 0s and 1s there are. You can try `Tally /@ mytable` to see the difference. The `N` in the second line tells it to return decimal numbers (0.25) rather than exact numbers (1/4). The number sign is a `Slot` which is basically just a placeholder. I'm dividing the second-row second-column value of each list that I put into $tally$. The first list in $tally$ looks like: `{{0, 27}, {1, 9}}` telling us there are 27 zeroes and 9 ones. So all the second row does is go 9/(9+27) to get us 1/4.

You can now easily combine this with the list of n values:

```
{{7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255}, fractions*100}\[Transpose]//TableForm
```

I have to multiply the fractions by 100 to get percentages, and the `\[Transpose]` is there to put them into nice columns. The `//TableForm` takes the whole thing and turns it into a nice table.

Answer (score 2):

```
Join @@ Table[
  Table[
   {p, q, 180 (1 - 2 q/p)},
   {q, Select[Range[1, Ceiling[p/2] - 1], CoprimeQ[p, #] &]}],
  {p, Select[Divisors[360], Between[{3, 40}]]}
  ]
```

Comment: It really would be nicer were you to make your answers self-contained w.r.t. evaluation.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't understand. What is the matter? This is supposed to be self-contained. Well, I'll check when I am back at my keyboard.

Comment: I apologize. It ***is*** self-contained. I didn't read it carefully enough. Also, thrown off because you didn't show results.

Comment: @m_goldberg No problem. The output was a bit lengthy and also already known, so I decided to leave it away. Anyways, I am going to take more care for self-containedness in the future; that won't harm.